# imshow() function freezes

Tags: c++, opencv

I am developing some video analytic algorithms using openCV. However, after I process a frame and want to display it on a window, it hangs at imshow() function. I have searched for this issue online but still cannot find the problem! Here is the code where I am using multithread and openCV:

```
void CFeatureExtraction::extract(){
    boost::thread OpFlowThread, BGSThread;
    while (m_nRun){
        ImgPtr frame_ptr;
        m_pQueue->wait_and_pop(frame_ptr);
        Mat frame1, frame2; 
        (*frame_ptr).copyTo(frame1);
        (*frame_ptr).copyTo(frame2);

        OpFlowThread = boost::thread(&COpFlow::op_flow, m_pAlgo,frame1);
        BGSThread = boost::thread(&CBGSub::bgsub, m_pBGS, frame2);
        OpFlowThread.join();
        BGSThread.join();
    }
}
```

And inside op_flow and bgsub function, I am using imshow() and cvWaitKey() together! But it keeps hanging the whole program.
If my question is still not clear for you, pls feel free to ask me for more detail.
Here is the detail code of calling imshow():

```
CFarnebackAlgo::CFarnebackAlgo() : COpFlow()
{
    namedWindow("Optical Flow");
}

CFarnebackAlgo::~CFarnebackAlgo()
{
    destroyWindow("Optical Flow");
}

int CFarnebackAlgo::op_flow(Mat frame)
{
   Mat flow;
   cvtColor(frame, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
   if (prevgray.data)
   {
       calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray, gray, flow, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0);

       for (int y = 0; y < frame.rows; y += 8)
           for (int x = 0; x < frame.cols; x += 8){
           const Point2f& fxy = flow.at<Point2f>(y, x);
           line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(cvRound(x + fxy.x), cvRound(y + fxy.y)),    Scalar(0, 255, 0));
           circle(frame, Point(x, y), 2, Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1);
           }
       if (frame.data == NULL){
           cout << "No Img!" << endl;
           exit(0);
       }
       imshow("Optical Flow", frame);
       waitKey(50);
   }
   std::swap(prevgray, gray);
   return 0;
}
```

If I put the namedWindow() in the op_flow(), it is working. But if I put it in the constructor, it's not working and freezes. Anyone knows why?

Comment: imshow/waitKey wasn't made for multithreading. period. if you *must* use threads, at least keep those calls in the main one. also please *don't* pass cv::Mat as a pointer(use refs or the plain thing), you'll inevitably thrash the internal refcounts.

Comment: Hi @berak, thanks for pointing out! But is there any solution for calling those funcs inside the thread itself. Because after doing optical flow, i need to display it immediately.

Comment: Hi @berak, I just added some code, pls take a look!